# How to print a circulant matrix (toeplitz), in MATLAB, where each input is a 3D matrix of dimention m x m x 3?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, toeplitz

I know how to use `toeplitz` function in MATLAB to create a circulant matrix of 1 D vector. However, I am trying to create a circulant block

For example, I have 3 matrices of size (2,2,3) where third dimension is R,G, B:
Below I am showing the sample values of row and column of each matrix. 
First Matrix:

```
# 01  02
# 03  04
```

Second Matrix:

```
# 05  06
# 07  08
```

Third Matrix:

```
# 09  10
# 11  12
```

Now I want to create a circulant matrix which looks like this

```
# 01  02  05  06  09  10
# 03  04  07  08  11  12
# 09  10  01  02  05  06
# 11  12  03  04  07  08
# 03  04  09  10  01  02
# 05  06  11  12  03  04
```

Note, I want to be able to move the entire block of the matrix to the right in the subsequent lines, and not just the first line of the matrix. Please note, i want to preserve the third dimensions of these matrices w(which has color dimension in them)

Can someone tell me how to go ahead with it? I thought of making an array I already have a 3D matrix, and don't know how to make an array of the array here, if it will help at all.

References:

- Toeplitz command in MATLAB: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html
- A Stackoverflow I was trying to understand but couldn't: [Matlab: How to convert a matrix into a Toeplitz matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610045/matlab-how-to-convert-a-matrix-into-a-toeplitz-matrix/35662046) (not yet sure if i answers my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code builds a linear index as the sum of two parts:

- an "outer" pattern describing the structure of blocks (generated with [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html)), and
- an "inner" pattern with the structure of a block repeated (using [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)).

Applying this index to the original matrix produces the desired result.

```
data = cat(3, [1 2; 3 4], [5 6; 7 8], [9 10; 11 12]); % example data
[L, M, N] = size(data);
ind_outer = repelem(mod(bsxfun(@minus, 0:N-1, (0:N-1).'), N), L, M);
ind_inner = repmat(reshape(1:L*M, L, M), N, N);
ind = ind_outer*L*M + ind_inner;
result = data(ind);
```

This gives

```
result =
     1     2     5     6     9    10
     3     4     7     8    11    12
     9    10     1     2     5     6
    11    12     3     4     7     8
     5     6     9    10     1     2
     7     8    11    12     3     4
```

To better understand how this works, see the outer and inner indexing patterns (and if needed read about [linear indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/)):

```
>> ind_outer
ind_outer =
     0     0     1     1     2     2
     0     0     1     1     2     2
     2     2     0     0     1     1
     2     2     0     0     1     1
     1     1     2     2     0     0
     1     1     2     2     0     0

>> ind_inner
ind_inner =
     1     3     1     3     1     3
     2     4     2     4     2     4
     1     3     1     3     1     3
     2     4     2     4     2     4
     1     3     1     3     1     3
     2     4     2     4     2     4
```